# What does it make Cell Max to be stronger than the original?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

So apparently Akira Toriyama stated that if Cell Max would have been completed, he could be stronger than Broly. And Cell Max gave serious problems to Orange Piccolo and Mystic Gohan. So, what's the reason this version of Cell is stronger than the original? Is it ever stated what made Cell Max much more powerful than the original Cell?

Comment: Do you happen to have a reference to where Akira Toriyama said this?  Although, in either context, it could just be raw speculation since it didn't happen and at this point in the franchise, I don't think Toriyama was as deeply embedded with character design and scale as he was in the early days.

Comment: There are many websites stating it, where was the interview I dont know.  "Akira Toriyama himself suggests that Broly is still stronger than Cell Max, but only because the latter was released in an incomplete form.  Otherwise, Cell would have been stronger than Broly." https://www.opticflux.com/is-cell-stronger-than-broly-in-dragon-ball-super-super-hero-akira-toriyama-brings-unexpected-answer/22006/#:~:text=Akira%20Toriyama%20himself%20suggests%20that,t%20even%20capable%20of%20speaking.

Comment: In a series of statements, which were translated and shared online by Twitter user @Herms98, series creator Akira Toriyama offered a few new details about Super Hero's surprise antagonist, . According to Toriyama, Cell Max is also substantially more powerful than the original incarnation of the character https://www.cbr.com/dragon-ball-super-hero-cell-max-broly-toriyama-movie/